# How to use .jsf extension in URLs?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, url-pattern, servlet-mapping

I'm developing a JSF 2 web application. For prestige purpouses I would like that every URL ends with `.jsf` extension. Now it ends with `.xhtml`. If I change it directly to `.jsf` in web browser address bar, then a HTTP 500 error is shown.

How can I set it to `.jsf`?

Comment: Nowadays it's prestige purpose to end it with `.do`.

Comment: @RomanC   Wasn't .do the popular thing in 2001? (Struts 1) Nowadays not using an extension at all might be cooler ;) For JSF you can use OmniFaces or PrettyFaces for that.

Comment: It's so popular as for they add it to each ISBN, for example http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596005726.do

Comment: @RomanC: please stop talking nonsense. You're only confusing starters. The `*.do` is typically used in Struts1 applications. Struts1 is just one of the many MVC frameworks and not a world wide web standard or something. For JSF, typically `*.xhtml`, `*.jsf`, `*.faces` or `/faces/*` is been used.

Answer (score 17):

The URL pattern of JSF pages is specified by `<servlet-mapping>` of the `FacesServlet` in `web.xml`. As you mentioned that `.xhtml` works fine, you have apparently configured it as follows:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>
```

You need to change the `<url-pattern>` accordingly to get the desired virtual URL extension.

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>      
</servlet-mapping>
```

That's all you need to change in order to achieve the concrete functional requirement, really.

**However**, this puts a security problem open. The enduser can now see the raw Facelets file source code when changing the extension in the URL back from `.jsf` to `.xhtml`. You can prevent this by adding the following security constraint to `web.xml`:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Restrict access to Facelets source code.</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Facelets</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: can we alternatively ease this security problem by copying our .xhtml files to WEF-INF?

Comment: @abbas: files in `/WEB-INF` are not publicly accessible. Just set JSF mapping to `*.xhtml`. No need to hassle with virtual URLs.

Answer (score 2):

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
  <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
 </context-param>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct. This is the extension for the actual file on disk. OP probably want the URL suffix, which you change via the url-pattern in the servlet-mapping in web.xml (or by omitting web.xml as *.jsf is the default in JSF 2.1).

Comment: Forget the previous comment, comment was for another answer that said to change default_suffix only. In this case, the servlet-mapping is enough, no need to change default_suffix.

Comment: Thenk you for your Answer which is probably correct regarding other sources. Sorry for delay - i was at Vacation, could I ask for one more help? When I use it and acces page.jsf (page.xhtml exist on server side) null pointer exeption is thrown, where could be the problem? There is web.xml: http://pastebin.com/3NqyYXSL and there is stack print http://pastebin.com/g76TgabF

Comment: The context param is completely unnecessary. This piece of code originates from a JSF 1.x + Facelets 1.x application.

Answer (score -1):

```
you can add this code in your web.xml, and you can run your pages ends with xhtml, jsf or faces
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```